# Warning: Illegal string offset 'message' in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\model\setting\chat.php on line 4

Tags: mysql, database, opencart, warnings

**Getting Warning message**

> : Illegal string offset 'message' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\model\setting\chat.php on line 4

Why i am getting this Warning And my data not inserting in database

Comment: Please share your query here

Comment: Which `opencart` version are you referring to? What `action` are you performing which giving you this `warning`